# How do I open a .pdf or .doc file in an Android app from MySQL's phpMyAdmin?

Tags: android-studio

I want to view an uploaded .doc file in my Android app from MySQL's [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin). How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: What did you find on Stack Overflow when you searched for this? Useless answers? Please demonstrate the effort you put into this before asking this question. It is OK to answer here in comments. Thanks in advance. [Related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbIvR3mqqyY&list=PLTbIqtg8Gb0pdq7RBIxAdtw7HGb1jimPg&index=6)

Comment: Where is phpMyAdmin running? On your [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) phone? On some web hosting?

Comment: It is running in my laptop